# Not implemented exception was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Everytime I try to print the error shows up.
it says "Not implemented exception was unhandled by user code".
how to fix this sh!t?
here's my code

```
namespace RunwayMedlinc
{
public partial class patient : Form
{
    Print print;
    MySqlConnection con;
    String sql;
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    MySqlDataAdapter data, data2, data3;
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
    DataTable table3 = new DataTable();
    DataSet da = new DataSet();
    int age;

    public patient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void view()
    {
    try
        {
            sql = "select p.mrn AS 'MRN', pp.name AS 'PATIENT NAME', pp.bday AS 'BIRTHDAY', p.age AS 'AGE', pp.gender AS 'GENDER',  p.admit AS 'ADMIT DATE', p.discharge AS 'DISCHARGE DATE', p.md AS 'PHYSICIAN'FROM p inner join pp ON p.mrn=pp.mrn where admit like'%" + year.Text + "%' and admit like'%" + month.Text + "%'";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            data.SelectCommand = cmd;
            pview.DataSource = table;
            table.Clear();
            data.Fill(table);
            pview.DataSource = table;
        }
        catch (Exception exx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exx.Message, "Error");
        }
    }

    public void bew()
    {
        try
        {
            sql = "select p.mrn AS 'MRN', pp.name AS 'PATIENT NAME', pp.bday AS 'BIRTHDAY', p.age AS 'AGE', pp.gender AS 'GENDER',  p.admit AS 'ADMIT DATE', p.discharge AS 'DISCHARGE DATE', p.md AS 'PHYSICIAN'FROM p inner join pp ON p.mrn=pp.mrn where admit like'%" + year2.Text + "%' and admit like'%" + month2.Text + "%'";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            data2.SelectCommand = cmd;
            pview2.DataSource = table2;
            table2.Clear();
            data2.Fill(table2);
        }
        catch (Exception exx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exx.Message, "Error");
        }
    }

    private void search_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (search.ForeColor == Color.Gray)
        {
            search.Clear();
            search.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }

    private void search_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (search.Text == "")
        {
            search.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            search.Text = "SEARCH PATIENT...";
        }
    }

    private void search2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (search2.ForeColor == Color.Gray)
        {
            search2.Clear();
            search2.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }

    private void search2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (search2.Text == "")
        {
            search2.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            search2.Text = "SEARCH PATIENT...";
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
        date.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy");
    }

    private void patient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new MySqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "server=Localhost;" + "username=root;" + "password=;" + "database=runway";
        con.Open();
        sql = "select mrn from p";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        data = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        data2 = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        month.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"));
        year.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));

        month2.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"));
        year2.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));

        view();

        bew();
    }

    private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mrn.Clear();
        name.Clear();
        phy.Clear();
        m.Checked = false;
        f.Checked = false;
        bdate.Value = DateTime.Now;
        admit.Value = DateTime.Now;
        disch.Value = DateTime.Now;

        add.Enabled = true;
        mrn.ReadOnly = false;
        name.ReadOnly = false;
        phy.ReadOnly = false;
        m.Enabled = true;
        f.Enabled = true;
        bdate.Enabled = true;
        admit.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void phy_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (phy.ReadOnly == false)
        {
            phy.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mrn.Text == "" || name.Text == "" || (m.Checked == false && f.Checked == false))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all information.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }
        else
        {
                DateTime x = admit.Value;
                DateTime y = bdate.Value;
                if (x.Month < y.Month || (x.Month == y.Month && x.Day < y.Day))
                {
                    age = x.Year - y.Year - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    age = x.Year - y.Year;
                }

                if (m.Checked == true)
                {
                    if (name.ReadOnly == false)
                    {
                        sql = "insert into pp(mrn, name, gender, bday)values (?a, ?b, ?c, ?d)";
                        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?a", mrn.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?b", name.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?c", m.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?d", bdate.Text);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                if (f.Checked == true)
                {
                    if (name.ReadOnly == false)
                    {
                        sql = "insert into pp(mrn, name, gender, bday)values (?a, ?b, ?c, ?d)";
                        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?a", mrn.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?b", name.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?c", f.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?d", bdate.Text);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                sql = "insert into p(mrn, admit, discharge, md, age)values (?a, ?e, ?f, ?g, ?z)";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?a", mrn.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?e", admit.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?f", null);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?g", phy.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?z", age);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Patient Successfully Added!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                mrn.Clear();
                name.Clear();
                phy.Text = "MANGASEP, CONCEPCION R.";
                m.Checked = false;
                f.Checked = false;
                bdate.Value = DateTime.Now;
                admit.Value = DateTime.Now;
                disch.Value = DateTime.Now;

                month2.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"));
                year2.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
                bew();

        }
    }

    private void search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (search.ForeColor != Color.Gray)
        {
            try
            {
                sql = "select p.mrn AS 'MRN', pp.name AS 'PATIENT NAME', pp.bday AS 'BIRTHDAY', p.age AS 'AGE', pp.gender AS 'GENDER',  p.admit AS 'ADMIT DATE', p.discharge AS 'DISCHARGE DATE', p.md AS 'PHYSICIAN'FROM p inner join pp ON p.mrn=pp.mrn where admit like'%" + year.Text + "%' and admit like'%" + month.Text + "%' and name like'%" + search.Text + "%'";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
                data.SelectCommand = cmd;
                pview.DataSource = table;
                table.Clear();
                data.Fill(table);
            }
            catch (Exception exx)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exx.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
    }

    private void search2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (search2.ForeColor != Color.Gray)
        {
            try
            {
                sql = "select p.mrn AS 'MRN', pp.name AS 'PATIENT NAME', pp.bday AS 'BIRTHDAY', p.age AS 'AGE', pp.gender AS 'GENDER',  p.admit AS 'ADMIT DATE', p.discharge AS 'DISCHARGE DATE', p.md AS 'PHYSICIAN'FROM p inner join pp ON p.mrn=pp.mrn where admit like'%" + year2.Text + "%' and admit like'%" + month2.Text + "%' and name like'%" + search2.Text + "%'";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
                data2.SelectCommand = cmd;
                pview2.DataSource = table2;
                table2.Clear();
                data2.Fill(table2);
            }
            catch (Exception exx)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exx.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
    }

    private void pview2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mrn.Text = pview2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        name.Text = pview2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        if (pview2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "MALE")
        {
            m.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            f.Checked = true;
        }
        bdate.Text = pview2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        admit.Text = pview2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        phy.Text = pview2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();

        add.Enabled = false;
        mrn.ReadOnly = true;
        name.ReadOnly = true;
        phy.ReadOnly = true;
        m.Enabled = false;
        f.Enabled = false;
        bdate.Enabled = false;
        admit.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sql = "Update p set discharge= '" + disch.Text + "' where mrn = '" + mrn.Text + "'";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Patient Successfuly Updated!");

        add.Enabled = true;
        mrn.Clear();
        mrn.ReadOnly = false;
        name.Clear();
        name.ReadOnly = false;
        phy.Text = "MANGASEP, CONCEPCION R.";
        phy.ReadOnly = false;
        m.Checked = false;
        f.Checked = false;
        bdate.Value = DateTime.Now;
        admit.Value = DateTime.Now;
        disch.Value = DateTime.Now;

        month2.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"));
        year2.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
        bew();
    }

    private void mrn_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sql = "Select name, gender, bday from pp where mrn = '" + mrn.Text + "'";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        data3 = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        data3.SelectCommand = cmd;
        table3 = new DataTable();
        data3.Fill(table3);

        if (table3.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            name.Text = Convert.ToString(table3.Rows[0][0]);
            if (Convert.ToString(table3.Rows[0][1]) == "MALE")
            {
                m.Checked = true; ;
            }
            else
            {
                f.Checked = true;
            }
            bdate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(table3.Rows[0][2]);
            name.ReadOnly = true;
            m.Enabled = false;
            f.Enabled = false;
            bdate.Enabled = false;

        }
        else
        {
            name.Clear();
            m.Checked = false;
            f.Checked = false;
            bdate.Value = DateTime.Now;
            name.ReadOnly = false;
            m.Enabled = true;
            f.Enabled = true;
            bdate.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void year_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        view();
    }

    private void month_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        view();
    }

    private void mrn_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
            (e.KeyChar != '.'))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        month.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"));
        year.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));

        month2.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"));
        year2.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
        search.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        search.Text = "SEARCH PATIENT...";
        search2.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        search2.Text = "SEARCH PATIENT...";
        mrn.Clear();
        name.Clear();
        phy.Text = "MANGASEP, CONCEPCION R.";
        m.Checked = false;
        f.Checked = false;
        bdate.Value = DateTime.Now;
        admit.Value = DateTime.Now;
        disch.Value = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void month2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bew();
    }

    private void year2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bew();
    }

    private bool SetupThePrinting()
     {
         PrintDialog MyPrintDialog = new PrintDialog();
         MyPrintDialog.AllowCurrentPage = false;
         MyPrintDialog.AllowPrintToFile = false;
         MyPrintDialog.AllowSelection = false;
         MyPrintDialog.AllowSomePages = false;
         MyPrintDialog.PrintToFile = false;
         MyPrintDialog.ShowHelp = false;
         MyPrintDialog.ShowNetwork = false;
         if (MyPrintDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
         return false;
         dokumento.DocumentName = "List of Patients";
         dokumento.PrinterSettings = MyPrintDialog.PrinterSettings;
         dokumento.DefaultPageSettings = MyPrintDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings;
         dokumento.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
         dokumento.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(10, 10, 10, 10);
         dokumento.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = MyPrintDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape;
         print = new Print(pview, dokumento, true, true, Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "" + "Runway Medlinc"  + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + "List of Patients" 
         + Environment.NewLine + "" + Environment.NewLine + month.Text + "  " + year.Text, new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Color.Black, true);
         return true;
     }

    private void printer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (SetupThePrinting())
           {
               PrintPreviewDialog MyPrintPreviewDialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
               MyPrintPreviewDialog.Document = dokumento;
               MyPrintPreviewDialog.ShowDialog();
               dokumento.Print();
           }
       }

    private void dokumento_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
      {
          bool more = print.DrawDataGridView(e.Graphics);
          if (more == true)
          e.HasMorePages = true;
     }

}
}
```

Everytime I try to print the error shows up.
it says "Not implemented exception was unhandled by user code".
how to fix this sh!t?
and the other class is here

```
namespace RunwayMedlinc
{
class Print
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView pview;
    private System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument dokumento;
    private bool p;
    private bool p_2;
    private string p_3;
    private System.Drawing.Font font;
    private System.Drawing.Color color;
    private bool p_4;

    public Print(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView pview, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument dokumento, bool p, bool p_2, string p_3, System.Drawing.Font font, System.Drawing.Color color, bool p_4)
    {
        this.pview = pview;
        this.dokumento = dokumento;
        this.p = p;
        this.p_2 = p_2;
        this.p_3 = p_3;
        this.font = font;
        this.color = color;
        this.p_4 = p_4;
    }

    internal bool DrawDataGridView(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must implement `DrawDataGridView` method in `Print` class.

Comment: how to implement DrawDataGridView method in Print class?

Answer (score 1):

The [PrintDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx), by itself, has no way of knowing what it is you want to print. You've told it the formatting, but not the content.

The way to tell it is to draw the document, using the `System.Drawing` namespace mostly, using the [Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the event as the output device. The output device is a printer driver which will translate your lines, text, etc. into the appropriate code for rendering on your specific printer, e.g. Postscript, PCL, whatever. That doesn't matter to you. You just need to output text, lines, and images in a virtual two-dimensional space.

So

1. Put those methods back
2. Implement `DrawDataGridView` !!! Just do something simple for now so you know that it works, like

   ```
   internal bool DrawDataGridView(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics)
   {
       graphics.DrawString("Hello world!");
   }
   ```

Once you have that working, next you'll have to figure out how to render the contents of the document properly. But that could be another SO question.

Comment: tried it.. but there's a red line under graphics.DrawString("Hello world!");

Answer (score 0):

```
internal bool DrawDataGridView(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The `throw` line is causing the issue. You need to remove that line and add an implementation there.

Comment: As a short term fix, comment out the `throw new NotImplementedException();` line.

Comment: so I tried to remove the      internal bool DrawDataGridView(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }     and     private void dokumento_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
          {
              bool more = print.DrawDataGridView(e.Graphics);
              if (more == true)
              e.HasMorePages = true;
         }   but prints nothing..

Comment: Why did you remove doumento_PrintPage? Don't you need that to, um, print the page? SMH